# ArcMap: ETRS89 LAEA to GRS80 TM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have two layers and they just won't line up. I am a novice and tried a variety of things but I can't get it right.

My layers are in:

GRS_1980_Transverse_Mercator
ETRS_1989_LAEA

These are CORINE and Copernicus EUDEM layers, or layers derieved from them.

What should I do, and more importantly - how?

Comment: I think we will need a little more information about your layers as well as what you have tried so far.

Comment: I will provide more information just tell me what kind of information would be helpful. I tried project raster tool and making my own transformation but I probably didn't do it correctly so let's just assume I didn't do anything.

Comment: So if you add both layers to ArcMap and ignore the transformation warning, how far off are they? Are they mainly off north-south? Can you include the data extents and complete coordinate system definitions? You might also try posting at Esri's Geonet.